# EF Core DbDataReader result changing in interceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interceptor

guys.

I have a question about EF Core DbCommandInterceptor.

Let's have a class with 2 fields like this

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string SameData { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public Guid TestClassId { get; set; }
   
   [NotMapperd, MyAttr]
   public TestClass TestClass { get; set; }
}
```

where `User` and `TestClass` are both located in the different contexts (for example, `UserDbContext`, `TestDbContext`). `MyAttr` is the marker attribute, nothing more.

So, I want to write an interceptor that raises up each time we try to get info about `TestClass`es, but after data got it should get an additional data about User with cross-request to UserDbContext (It possible, because I have `User` `Id` after the command execution and can use this `Id` in the request)

I know, that it should be `DbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecuted` or `DbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecutedAsync` in this case, but I cannot understand how to get information about objects in the result (I can get rows but I cannot understand what should I do, how should I map it). I can use additional libraries in the project if needed (like Dapper and others).

Could anyone helps me to get

1. Result Type - concrete entity type or entity collection type?
2. Result as a C# object (POCO or POCO collection)?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are the entities on different DbContexts if they are related?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Let's imagine a situation. I have `User`s that store in `UserDbContext` and `Order`s that store in `OrderDbContext`. But `Order` still needs to store additional information about the `User` who made it. But these Entities, of course are strictly different and should be stored in different databases.

Comment: Why would different entities be stored in different databases?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Because I don't want to have logically different entities in one Database. Also, I want to divide storage and possibly have different databases on different machines.

Comment: Then write some DTOs and assemble your objects with calls you your various DbContexts.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I know that solution, also I can store just `Id` of each `User` I need, but I want to make my life a little bit easier with `NotMapped` field which makes most of additional work for me under the hood.

Comment: That's sot going to make your life easier.  If you want different repositories for your entities, you should handle this at a higher level.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I can use different approaches. But now I just want to understand how to inject additional data in `DbDataReader result` in `DbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecutedAsync` method. Unfortunally, EF Core documentation is too poor in this section (maybe I just have bad skill in searching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know, that it should be DbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecuted or DbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecutedAsync in this case, but I cannot understand how to get information about objects in the result

The EF Command interceptors don't support that.  You can replace the DataReader with a different one.  But the query was generated to fill a particular object graph, which is not exposed by the interceptor API.

Comment: But if I get an object of Type T in the result, I can change fields in it, can't I? So, I want to "inject" data in the result object, not in DbDataReader, my bad.

Comment: There's no interceptor for that.  Ie the object materialization layer doesn't have any of the kind of extensibility you are looking for.

Comment: So, there is no way even to get  Type of requested Data?

Comment: So, additional question: does EF Core support re-registration service for object materialization?

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15911